# How to take an object from a different class

Tags: ruby

I have two classes. Todo and TodoList.  I'm getting 2 error messages from the Todolist class which I think is because I've not yet correctly worked out how to pass an object from Todo to TodoList.  If that's the case how do I do that?

I have tried setting variables and running tests within Atom to close is on where I should be passing in the object (assuming that is what I should be doing). I've checked I've got the naming structure right after simply trying to pass the object as it is.

Heres what code I have right now:

```
class Todo

  def initialize(param)
    @param = param
  end

  def text
    return @param
  end
end

class TodoList

  def initialize
    @item_list = []
  end

  def add(item)
    @item = []
    @item << item
  end

  def print
    @item_list.each do |item|
      puts "* #{item}"
    end
  end
end
```

Here are the error messages:

```
 1) Q1. Todo list TodoList printing todos one todo prints a single todo with a bullet point
     Failure/Error: expect { todo_list.print }.to output("* get milk\n").to_stdout

       expected block to output "* get milk\n" to stdout, but output nothing
       Diff:
       @@ -1,2 +1 @@
       -* get milk

2) Q1. Todo list TodoList printing todos many todos prints the todos, separated by newlines
     Failure/Error: expect { todo_list.print }.to output(expected_output).to_stdout

       expected block to output "* get milk\n* get the paper\n* get orange juice\n" to stdout, but output nothing
       Diff:
       @@ -1,4 +1 @@
       -* get milk
       -* get the paper
       -* get orange juice

     # ./spec/question_1_spec.rb:63:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here is the test specification referred to in the errors:

```
context "one todo" do
        it "prints a single todo with a bullet point" do
          todo_list.add(todo)

          expect { todo_list.print }.to output("* get milk\n").to_stdout
        end
      end

      context "many todos" do
        let(:todo_1) { Todo.new("get milk") }
        let(:todo_2) { Todo.new("get the paper") }
        let(:todo_3) { Todo.new("get orange juice") }
        let(:todo_list) { TodoList.new }

        let(:expected_output) { ["* get milk",
                                "* get the paper",
                                "* get orange juice"].join("\n") +
                               "\n" }

        it "prints the todos, separated by newlines" do
          todo_list.add(todo_1)
          todo_list.add(todo_2)
          todo_list.add(todo_3)

          expect { todo_list.print }.to output(expected_output).to_stdout
        end
```

So I should be getting two things as an output:

a list with one item:

- get milk

and a list with 3 items:

- get milk
- get the paper
- get orange juice

but as it is I get nothing.

How do I pass an object from one class to the other (assuming that is the issue) and if it's not the issue what is?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see where you are trying to pass anything from Todo to TodoList. And the root of your problem is that you're populating one collection (there's a bug there, btw), but printing another. Naturally, the other collection comes up empty.

Comment: First thing which I am spotted is that each time you call `todo_list.add(item)` you clearing your `@item` by `@item = []` so every single time you will have only one item in `@item`, just move `@item=[]` to constructor and that should help, or just use `@item_list` when you adding items so `@item_list << item` should fix your issue

Comment: @SergioTulentsev you are right about trying to pass anything!  Had spent so much time guessing different things to get other errors fixed I lost sight of what I had right at the start and took myself down a completely different path.

Answer (score 1):

The `add` method is not correct. In the `initialize` method, you set `@item_list` to an empty array. But you don't add data to this variable in the `add` method and you use the `@item_list` variable in the `print` method. So in the `add` method you need to use the `@item_list` variable instead of the `@item` variable.

```
class TodoList
  ..
  def add(item)
    @item_list << item
  end
  ..
end
```